# Tokenizing the stop words generated tokens ['ha', 'le', 'u', 'wa'] not in stop_words

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, chatbot

I am making a chatbot using Python. 
Code:

```
import nltk
import numpy as np
import random
import string 
f=open('/home/hostbooks/ML/stewy/speech/chatbot.txt','r',errors = 'ignore')
raw=f.read()
raw=raw.lower()# converts to lowercase

sent_tokens = nltk.sent_tokenize(raw)# converts to list of sentences 
word_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)# converts to list of words

lemmer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()    

def LemTokens(tokens):
    return [lemmer.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens]

remove_punct_dict = dict((ord(punct), None) for punct in string.punctuation)

def LemNormalize(text):
    return LemTokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punct_dict)))

GREETING_INPUTS = ("hello", "hi", "greetings", "sup", "what's up","hey","hii")
GREETING_RESPONSES = ["hi", "hey", "*nods*", "hi there", "hello", "I am glad! You are talking to me"]


def greeting(sentence):
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word.lower() in GREETING_INPUTS:
            return random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

def response(user_response):
    robo_response=''
    sent_tokens.append(user_response)    

    TfidfVec = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=LemNormalize, stop_words='english')
    tfidf = TfidfVec.fit_transform(sent_tokens)
    vals = cosine_similarity(tfidf[-1], tfidf)
    idx=vals.argsort()[0][-2]
    flat = vals.flatten()
    flat.sort()
    req_tfidf = flat[-2]    

    if(req_tfidf==0):
        robo_response=robo_response+"I am sorry! I don't understand you"
        return robo_response
    else:
        robo_response = robo_response+sent_tokens[idx]
        return robo_response

flag=True
print("ROBO: My name is Robo. I will answer your queries about Chatbots. If you want to exit, type Bye!")

while(flag==True):
    user_response = input()
    user_response=user_response.lower()
    if(user_response!='bye'):
        if(user_response=='thanks' or user_response=='thank you' ):
            flag=False
            print("ROBO: You are welcome..")
        else:
            if(greeting(user_response)!=None):
                print("ROBO: "+greeting(user_response))
            else:
                print("ROBO: ",end="")
                print(response(user_response))
                sent_tokens.remove(user_response)
    else:
        flag=False
        print("ROBO: Bye! take care..")
```

It is running well but with every conversation it's giving this error:

```
/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py:300: UserWarning: Your stop_words may be inconsistent with your preprocessing. 

Tokenizing the stop words generated tokens ['ha', 'le', 'u', 'wa'] not in stop_words.
```

These are some conversations from CMD:

***ROBO: a chatbot is a piece of software that conducts a conversation via auditory or textual methods.***

*what is india*

```
    /home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py:300: UserWarning: Your stop_words may be inconsistent with your preprocessing. Tokenizing the stop words generated tokens ['ha', 'le', 'u', 'wa'] not in stop_words. 'stop_words.' % sorted(inconsistent))
```

***ROBO: india's wildlife, which has traditionally been viewed with tolerance in india's culture, is supported among these forests, and elsewhere, in protected habitats.***

*what is chatbot*

```
    /home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py:300: UserWarning: Your stop_words may be inconsistent with your preprocessing. Tokenizing the stop words generated tokens ['ha', 'le', 'u', 'wa'] not in stop_words. 'stop_words.' % sorted(inconsistent))
```

***ROBO: a chatbot is a piece of software that conducts a conversation via auditory or textual methods.***

Comment: Check out this work by https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W18-2502/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that you have used custom `tokenizer` and used default `stop_words='english'` so while extracting features a check is made to see if there is any inconsistency between `stop_words` and `tokenizer`

If you dig deeper into the code of `sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py` you will find this snippet performing the consistency check:

> ```
> def _check_stop_words_consistency(self, stop_words, preprocess, tokenize):
>     """Check if stop words are consistent
>
>     Returns
>     -------
>     is_consistent : True if stop words are consistent with the preprocessor
>                     and tokenizer, False if they are not, None if the check
>                     was previously performed, "error" if it could not be
>                     performed (e.g. because of the use of a custom
>                     preprocessor / tokenizer)
>     """
>     if id(self.stop_words) == getattr(self, '_stop_words_id', None):
>         # Stop words are were previously validated
>         return None
>
>     # NB: stop_words is validated, unlike self.stop_words
>     try:
>         inconsistent = set()
>         for w in stop_words or ():
>             tokens = list(tokenize(preprocess(w)))
>             for token in tokens:
>                 if token not in stop_words:
>                     inconsistent.add(token)
>         self._stop_words_id = id(self.stop_words)
>
>         if inconsistent:
>             warnings.warn('Your stop_words may be inconsistent with '
>                           'your preprocessing. Tokenizing the stop '
>                           'words generated tokens %r not in '
>                           'stop_words.' % sorted(inconsistent))
> ```

As you can see it raises warning if an inconsistency is found.

Hope it helps.

Comment: There're quite a few posts on stackoverflow about this problem but your answer is the only one that explains the underlying issue. Great job!